# What's the easiest, cheapest solution to build a E-Commerce website

Tags: e-commerce

It is for a small business, looking for the best solution... Did a search and only came up with very specific question related to ecommerce

Comment: Need many more details than this. What do you intend to sell? What sort of web development are you experienced with?

Comment: my knowledge is very limited, the business sells kitchen utilities.. I'm a computer science student, and i know some html/CSS, the guy knows i'm a total newbie, and i'm treating as a learning experience as i set it...

Also besides the point, i'm a very good computer scientist and a very quick learner when it comes to anything with computers

Comment: also i will be meeting with the guy on wednesday and i will have a better idea on the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be worth taking a look at http://shopify.com/

Answer (score 3):

[OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) is a well proven, free ecommerce solution, which is easy to set up

Comment: Yes, it is what I know and is well known shopping cart application.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider just opening up an eBay store :) That way you essentially get free advertising, search engine indexing etc.

Comment: Additionally this covers security both in the technical sense, and in terms of customer perception.

Answer (score 2):

I always suggest that a company that is very small start with an open source solution such as [DashCommerce](http://dashcommerce.org/default.aspx).  This way you get the development experience of the people supporting that project, plus the tested framework that many other companies are already using.  The more people that use the code base the more reliable it is.  Also, the more plugin type features that it might support such as tax, shipping, etc.

Take a look at [DashCommerce's feature list](http://dashcommerce.org/dashCommerce/featuresmatrix.aspx) to get an idea of what a complete ecommerce system should have.

Comment: this looks very good, what kinda background knowledge would i need to be able to put up this site?

Comment: The site actually comes with an installer.  All you need to do is have an empty database and sql account to allow the installer to get in and install the db.  Then create a website and point the installer to your web server and it will take care of the rest.  You can choose to install with a sample product catalog to play with or an empty installation to start building your store.  Once you get it installed working with the admin portal is very easy with help scattered all over the place.  Very easy to work with!

Comment: FYI this is a SQL Server / ASP.NET application and so would work best under IIS, windows server, etc.  You can usually get this app running in a hosted environment if you don't have direct access to your servers.

Comment: that does sound easy, i will prolly start with the sample catalog...then do the web server and stuff.. .Also they don't have an existing website, so hopefully dashcommerce can take care of it all

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo! Stores](http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/ecommerce/) has one of the easiest ecommerce setups and has low upfront costs. The ongoing fees is how they make their money, and it becomes expensive with more volume.